# Angularjs : can't recognize ngTable in Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am developing a web application by using angularjs as front end. I am using ngTable for my table design. In my index.html, I add the following code.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet"; href="https://unpkg.com/ng-table@2.0.2/bundles/ng-table.min.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/ng-table@2.0.2/bundles/ng-table.min.js"></script>
```

Next, I add ngTable into my app.js

```
angular.module('AssetManagementApp', ['ngRoute','angularMoment', 'ngTable'])
```

But when I add ngTable into controller.js. The following is my code.

angular.module('AssetManagementApp')

```
.controller('PCAssetManagementController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
        $scope.softwareTable = new ngTableParams({
            page: 1,
            count: 10
        }, {
            total: $scope.users.length, 
            getData: function ($defer, params) {
                $scope.data = $scope.users.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());
                $defer.resolve($scope.data);
            }
        });

    }])
```

The web application crash when I inject 'ngTable' into controller. If I remove ngTable in controller.js. The application back to normal. However, the application still works well when the 'ngTable' is injected into app.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also have to inject the `ngTableParams` into your controller:

```
angular.module('AssetManagementApp').controller('PCAssetManagementController', ['$scope', '$http', 'NgTableParams', function($scope, $http, NgTableParams){
    $scope.softwareTable = new NgTableParams({
        page: 1,
        count: 10
    }, {
        total: $scope.users.length, 
        getData: function ($defer, params) {
            $scope.data = $scope.users.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());
            $defer.resolve($scope.data);
        }
    });

}])
```

Comment: Even I add ngTableParams into .controller('PCAssetManagementController', ['$scope', '$http', 'ngTableParams', function($scope, $http, ngTableParams). It still have the same problem.

Comment: Sorry, it was with a capital N: `NgTableParams`. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Still have the same problem. The main problem is the program can't recognize ngTableParams' for controller injection.

Comment: [Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/0cG322Bu1Tl58BAnKebu?p=preview) is working example of ngTable usage.